# How to disable multi click on button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multi-touch

I have a UITableView:

**Cell 1:** *Button 1->push to view controller A*

**Cell 2:** *Button 2->push to view controller B*

It works fine. However, when I try to hold and press two buttons at the same time, my app receives ***following*** warning:

> nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar.
>   Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.
>   Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

How should I disable multi click button on cell ?

Comment: There is property in IB .. Selection options is there you can select single selection option.

Comment: hi.. you have not replied.

Comment: @AshokLondhe: I'm so sorry. I just go out.
I've tried to set single selection. But it didn't work too.

Comment: there are two options 1) Selection 2)Editing. Set this two option and try. i am sure your problem getting solved.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to disable the button while pushing to another View Controller.
You can create category of`UINavigationController` for pushing to another view Controller. Make sure that you enable the button before coming back to current viewController

```
@interface UINavigationController (CompletionHandler)

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
              animated:(BOOL)animated
            completion:(void (^)(void))completion;

@end




@implementation UINavigationController (CompletionHandler)
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completion];
[self pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
[CATransaction commit];
}


@end
```

Call the below code for pushing to another ViewController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ControllerObj animated:YES completion:^{
        btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // Your Button Object
        NSLog(@"COMPLETED");
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set exclusive touch on e*ach cell's button*.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Get your cell

    cell.button.exclusiveTouch = YES;

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
cell.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Also disable the multiple touch property from the tableView

```
self.tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: @TienLe Try this too,  self.tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;

Comment: @TienLe There is selection property in IB you can select single selection option.

Answer (score 0):

if above method is not working then when one button is clicked you can disable the interaction with the cell

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Later as per your need or in `viewWillAppear` enable the same.

Comment: if he used cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO; then how it is possible to select single cell at a time.

Comment: @AshokLondhe He has to use this after clicking the cell in  `didSelectRow` or at the button action so that second click is disabled

Comment: you try this first. because it's not working. Try it .

Answer (score 0):

Change your button's IBAction forControllEvent as UIControlEventTouchDown.

if you use storyboard cell 
hook up your buttons action by changeing touchUpInside to touchDown.

or

```
[YOUR_BUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_IBACTION:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

This will prevent button touch and holding. and this Action will call push immediatly at your touch.