# How can I disable Multi Click for UIButton in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, multi-touch

I have two buttons that have their own segue with identifiers. I want to disable the multiple clicks for these buttons so both cannot be clickable at the same time.

My code :

```
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.view.exclusiveTouch = true
```

I tried this code in `viewDidLoad` but didn't work.

Comment: the code you posted has nothing to do with button. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251663/how-to-disable-multi-click-on-button I found this code in here. Why are you telling this is nothing. I know that doesn't work. I'm asking because of that. Question title is very clear. So weird 3 downvote in 10 minutes.

Comment: So you have two buttons that each push a new viewController?

Comment: you need to provide more details of what you are trying to do and what the issue is! You can't just post one line of irrelevant code and say it didn't work.@yesman

Comment: There are a number of answers to the linked question.  Did you try setting the `exclusiveTouch` property to `true` for each of the buttons in the Storyboard or in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Ok I added some more clear explain and code.

Comment: @vacawama yes, I tried but didn't work. I'm clicking 3 buttons, all of them working and opening all pages one by one.

Comment: You should be setting `exclusiveTouch` to `true` for each of your buttons.  Are you doing that, and where?

Comment: some buttons have triggered segues. I tried these codes on `viewDidLoad`. So I create event for this buttons and added this code. Am I truly understand?

Comment: @yesman, I added code to do what you want. Give that a try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `@IBOutlet`s for each of your buttons by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from each button to the viewController and give them unique names such as `button1`, `button2` and `button3`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, set the `exclusiveTouch` property to `true` for each of the buttons:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button1.exclusiveTouch = true
    button2.exclusiveTouch = true
    button3.exclusiveTouch = true
```

This will prevent a second button from being pressed while the pressing of the first one is in process.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. Also for the nav bars : `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.exclusiveTouch = true`

Comment: extension UIButton {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        
        self.isEnabled=false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.isEnabled = true
        }
        
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really *not* clear, but I suppose you're stuck with a very common problem which is solved by setting the property `exclusiveTouch` (see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch)) to `true` for all your buttons.